# Cannot load such file -- inifile (LoadError) Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm facing the below issue while executing my ruby script. Any ideas ?

```
D:\my_ruby>ruby format.rb

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    : cannot load such file -- inifile (LoadError)
            from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
    :in `require'

            from format.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Windows 7 64 bit

Ruby version - ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x64-mingw32]

Bundler version 1.15.1

gem - v: 2.6.11

I tried running `bundle update` but still the same issue.

code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'inifile'

def transform_data(data)
  groups = data.delete('groups').map do |k,v|
    values = v.split(',').map(&:strip).map do |v|
      v.gsub(/[\n\r\0\t]/) do |char|
        case char
        when "\0" then '\0'
        when "\n" then '\n'
        when "\r" then '\r'
        when "\t" then '\t'
        end
      end
    end

    [k, values]
  end.to_h

  data.flat_map do |endpoint, attrs|
    attrs.flat_map do |cluster, access_level|
      c = cluster.gsub('@', '')
      groups[c].map do |id|
        {
          cluster: c,
          id: id,
          case: endpoint,
          access_level: access_level
        }
      end
    end
  end
end

records = File.read('input.txt').split(/(#.*\n|\*+\n)/).each_slice(4).flat_map do |r|
  data = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new }
  IniFile::Parser.new(data, '=', ';#', 'global').parse r[2]

  file_name = r[0][/(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=-values\.txt)/]

  transform_data(data).map { |d| { file_name: file_name }.merge(d) }
end

CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
  csv << records.first.keys
  records.each do |hash|
    csv << hash.values
  end
end
```

Comment: Can we see the source code please?

Comment: @Paul Coleman : I've added the code on my question. Thanks.

Comment: How did you installed `inifile`?

Comment: @Gerry : from the command line,  I have installed the gem `gem install inifile`

Comment: Apparently that gem has not being updated in a long time (3 years), so my guess is that it is not compatible with ruby 2.4. You could try to use install an earlier ruby version or skip that gem.

Comment: No, i would not recommend going to 1.9.x (not even below 2.3) unless a very good reason to do so, and a gem that is (apparently) not maintained is not. But then again, this is my _guess_ you should confirm that the issue is in fact that gem (for example, try using other gems). If that gem is indeed the problem, then i would recommend finding another way to work with _ini_ files.

Comment: @Gerry : Thanks a lot for your suggestion, Its not an inifile but a txt file , i thought of parsing like ini file. Any alternate suggestions how to parse it apart from ini. If required I can raise a new question with requirement .Thanks again for your time.

Comment: This is another potential gem [props](https://github.com/rubylibs/props/tree/master/props). I haven't tried this!

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me when I upgraded from Ruby 2.0 to Ruby 2.4. Just install the `inifile` gem: `gem install inifile`. The issue should be gone.